# Using Firefox Poster extension with non-Google credentials

Tags: firefox, oauth, firefox-addon, yql, poster

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the Firefox [Poster extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/poster/) for restful web services with "User Auth:" credentials that are non-Google?

Comment: So, what kind of authentication are we talking about? HTTP Basic Auth? OAuth 1.0? OAuth 2.0? They are all very different...

Answer (score 0):

The Poster extension currently supports only HTTP Basic Auth and authorization by Google login. For OAuth you would need to get an access token yourself and add an `Authorization` header manually - not trivial, especially for OAuth 1.0. Feel free to ask the extension author about OAuth support or (better) propose an implementation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I have been able to generate the access token but I'm not sure of how to use it within poster.